# How can I disable avatar in jitsi meet

Tags: android, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using jitsi meet in my android app. but I would like to disable the view where is shows user avatar, I do not want to change it , just completely hide that view. I know we can make change by modifying `interface_config.js` , but not sure , which variable to change .

Answer (score 0):

With `setFeatureFlag()` you can change UI chat:

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()          
          .setRoom(url)
          .setSubject(" ")
          .setFeatureFlag("chat.enabled", false)
          .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled", false)          
          .setFeatureFlag("calendar.enabled", false)
          .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
          .build();
```